# How to hide image to centre point of the image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a problem where, I want to show/hide images to the centre point of the image.

I have used jquery animate function like

```
  $("someId").animate({width:"hide"},300);
```

It is hiding the image from bottom-right to top-left.  I want to hide an image to the centre point of the image.

Comment: the sentence *I want to show/hide images to the centre point of the image.* makes no sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: if I animate the image, the animation goes towards top-left.  I want a hiding effect to the centre point of the image. for ex: if image size is 100px X 100px. the effect should be towards the point 50px X 50Px

Comment: I think Twilight sun has your solution. You'll need to use a div and shrink that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **[JqueryUI effect](http://jqueryui.com/hide/)** for achieve your expected result,use scale effect

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/AALx7/)**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('img').hide("scale",1000);
});
```

Comment: It is flickering upon loaded in the server.  So, I used TweenMax to solve this

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using <img> tag, instead you are using the image as the background of a div.

You can set the background using css : `background: url(...) no-repeat center center`. And when you hide the div by shrinking, the image is centered.

Comment: @Abhiram well then that would be a little complicated. You need to wrap the image with a div, and set `overflow:hidden` on that div. Then you set `position:relative` on the img. Lastly when you animate, use `{left:-$("someId").width() / 2}` on the ing while `{width:"hide"}` goes to the div. You have to make sure that the wrapping div has the same dimensions with the image when not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a CSS hack. Set the margins of the image tag to -50% to make it have no width and then set its position to absolute and set top and left to 50%. This centers the image in its parent element. I recommend shrinking the parent element and setting overflow to hidden.

### Details:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img id="picture" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#picture{
    margin: -50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

You will also want to set the default wrapper to the size of the image. It is a fake clipping mask for the image and it doesn't know how big it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using TweenMax.js like this

```
 var w = $("#someId").position().left + ($("#physical"+i).width()/2);

 var h = $("#someId").position().top +  ($("#physical"+i).height()/2) ;

 TweenMax.to( $("#someId"),1,{ css:{width:0,height:0,left:w,top:h} } );
```